# toggling both buttons in fixed positioned at bottom

Tags: jquery

I have applied jQuery to a fixed positioned div as this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".buttontab a").click(function(){

        jQuery(".buttontab a.active").removeClass("active");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active").blur();
        jQuery(jQuery(this).attr("href")).slideToggle(1000);
        return false;
});
});
```

If the main div was not fixed at bottom it won't have problem but stacking in fixed position the jQuery is working as if both button has been called. Here is the demo from which you can understand properly.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TEn3w/1/)

How to stack one button at bottom while other button is opened?

Comment: I messed around with a bit, no success, but I do not think jquery is acting as though both buttons are being called but rather the window is being redrawn and the elements are positioning themselves relative to each other. Mostly based on an alert(this) call and some unsuccessful tweaking

Comment: @Four_lo Yeah! exactly that, but I am just saying **working as if **

Comment: I tried using inline-block instead of float for the positioning and instead of the second moving all of the way up it moved half about? found it interesting yet inconclusive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/TEn3w/4/

I used `display:inline-block;` instead of float to apply `vertical-align:bottom` on the buttons, plus I removed the margins from the `h4`

```
.buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.buttontab {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: could you please help me to slide down when another is slide up?

Comment: but it also slideToggle when you click again to same button when not clicking another

Comment: I decided against the 'open' class because we are using the same line to toggle open/close so we would have to check when it's actually opening and not closing. Also `jQuery('.open').not(this)` wouldn't work because the class was being applied to the content and `this` would refer to the link inside the click function, that's why I used `.not(jQuery(jQuery(this).attr("href")))`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/MWTVL/

check the link

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".buttontab a").click(function(){

        jQuery(".buttontab a").removeClass("active");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active").blur();
        jQuery(jQuery(this).attr("href")).slideToggle(1000);
        return false;
});
});
```